# Filter incoming calls in iPhone

Tags: iphone

Is there any ways to filter incoming calls in iPhone. Suppose I am getting a call from unknown number then I want that this call will go to my voice mail.If calls from any of group within my address book then busy ringtone.etc.... 
Is this possible in iPhone programatically. Any help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think this would be better on http://gadgets.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to filter incoming calls is on a Jailbroken iPhone.
If thats your case search for iBlacklist.

Comment: Thanks marcos.Can u provide any sample code or tutorial for the same.

Comment: Sorry, all I know is that you have to use unpublished APIs. Search for "unpublished APIs" or "private APIs".

Answer (score -1):

For $5 a month you can use [AT&T Smart Limits](http://www.att.com/esupport/article.jsp?sid=KB92823&cv=820#fbid=0haY0NLIshN).